# Backup Library albums on onedrive

Tags: backup, camera, pc

How can I backup other albums in my PC library other than Camera Roll??

Comment: Can you leave some more detail? What exactly are you looking for? How do you want other albums backed up?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general computer software and therefor belong over at superuser.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I believe Sam is really talking about WP albums. This isn't off-topic but is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be done automatically. You can go into an album, select all photos and from there manually upload them to OneDrive.